# Is this is true , that a non cyclic group U(n) have not always cyclic subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm confused for that I had read somewhere that it is true...but how I don't know

Comment: The trivial subgroup $\{1\}$ is trivially cyclic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The claim is false.

Indeed, a more general fact is true:

> If $G$ is not cyclic, then $G$ has a proper nontrivial cyclic group.

Indeed, if $G$ is not cyclic, then it has an element $g \ne e$. Then $\langle g \rangle $ is a proper nontrivial cyclic group.